# How to prove the following series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

The $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {a_n}{n} $ where $a_n$ is any sequence that meets the condition: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$.

I have tried to apply the different tests available such as the limit comparison test and divergence test but I am not sure how to rigorously prove this statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The statement is false.

Comment: I heavily edited your question. Please be sure I did not change its meaning.

Comment: The answer you accepted does not answer your edited question.

Comment: The sum should start at $n=1$ since $\frac{a_n}n$ is bad for $n=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer to the question, but it shows that the question cannot be answered.

If
$$
a_n=\frac1{\log(n+1)}
$$
then the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}n
$$
does not converge.

Comment: Apply the Cauchy Condensation Test: If $ f(n) \geq f(n+1)\geq 0$ for all but  finitely many $n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ converges iff  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[2^n f(2^n)]$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

This not true, see $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a counterexample? The series $\sum n^{-3/2}$ converges.

Comment: When this answer was posted, OP was asking a completely different question @RRL

Comment: Got it. Thanks.